# Samsung Galaxy S7 Crash Getting Location

Tags: java, android, location

I have an app that has worked for a year on my Galaxy S6 and my Brother's Galaxy S4.
He recently bought a new Galaxy S7 and the App crashes when it tries to access the location services.
I've searched the internet diligently but I can't find any reference to why this might happen.
He has Location Services turned on and I've done the proper permission requests (as far as I can determine).
I've coded a much smaller app that just accesses the location services and gets a location which works fine on my S5 but it also crashes immediately upon initial execution when he runs this barebones app also.
I've included the code below hoping someone can help me find the problem:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    static LocationManager locationManager;
    public static double currentLat, currentLon;
    public static Location location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        //Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager

        String provider;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        if (locationManager != null) {
            if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            }
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        currentLat = location.getLatitude();
        currentLon = location.getLongitude();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();

                openMapActivity();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

        @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {


        if (locationManager != null) {
            if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            }
        }

        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);


    }


    public void openMapActivity(){
        // if bReady is false there hasn't been a new location recorded. Use the last known location to
        // place the camera on the map
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

And here is the Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.daknife.locationtest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you sure that getLastKnownLocation() returns not null ?

Comment: I put in a check to do a Toast and then stop if getLastKnownLocation()  returned null and it still crashed.

Comment: So whats the crash log ?

Comment: I took the suggestion a little further and the problem seems to be that getBestProvider() is returning null. Any suggestions for an alternate way to make that call?

Comment: Instead of getting getBestProvider, i suggest directly using gps or network providers. Or you could use fused location provider too.

Comment: I found the solution to the problem. Marshmallow has individual permissions for each app and the permission for Locations for my app wasn't turned on.

Comment: Hello @Daknife can you share how you resolved above issue?